# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): secp256k1.sign is not a function?

Tags: node.js, docker, ethereum

When i run my project in docker i have this `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): secp256k1.sign is not a function` error with ethereumjs.The project starts successfully, but when I call the action associated with this function, I get the error

Comment: Please edit the question and share the snippet defining `secp256k1` and calling the `sign` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.

The problem for me was that one of my dependencies was using the older [secp256k1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secp256k1) version (3.8) that doesn't have the same "sign" function as the 4.* versions.